# How do I select both frame and layer in timeline in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I am trying to do a frame animation and whenever I want to edit a frame I need to select the frame and then I also have to select the layer for that frame in the layers panel. Is there a keyboard shortcut or something so I can select both at the same time? This would really speed the editing process. I hope that my question makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are trying to accomplish but frames are frames and layers are layers, they are accomplishing separate tasks. You can try holding down the CTRL key on the frame then selecting the layer in question.

If you using the "create animation" (thumbnail) view of the Timeline it might be helpful for making changes to each frame. May I also suggest the "Match Across All Layers" function (right click on the timeline viewer while you have the editing layer in question) - this will allow you to make universal changes to the selected layers throughout all of your frames. I find this very handy when I've made a change to layer that I need to show on all frames. You can also accomplish this by holding down the SHFT key while selecting the layers you want to edit, then click on the layer you want to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, you can use the arrow keys to move through the frames when doing handdrawn stop frame and the shortcut to move up and down through the layers is <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> - still would be nice to automatically move through the layers or have an option to enable this on just one key to make it more like flipping pages in hand drawn animation.

Answer (score 0):

The thumb tack with the chain link, top left above layers
"Unify:"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112366)